# Error: response status 500 in Swagger UI when trying to test POST with database - Globalization Invariant Mode

Tags: c#, blazor

When trying to run a test through POST from my projects Swagger to my database, I get this error: System.NotSupportedException: Globalization Invariant Mode is not supported. Im new to C# and Blazor, but Im trying to have my mudblazor .net 8 blazor server project with asp.net api work flawlessly with a SSMS database, so that I can store user login information in it. Any way to fix this?

I ran both my blazor server and api at the same time. I decided to test out my API with the execute function on Swagger. The two variables "name" and "email" are there, but when I try to execute these values the Error: response status 500 shows up at the bottom and theres nothing in my database.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Could you give us some code? Cant tell you whats wrong with something we cant see

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.